# Do we want this Workplace SE Question about Scrum Master's performing Functional Management Roles?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration

There's a [post on Workplace SE - Scrum Master Performing Functional Manager Role](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14023/scrum-master-performing-functional-manager-role), that may be a better fit for this site.

It was asked on August 27th and only has 1 answer. Would the question be a good fit for this site?

As an aside, I oftentimes drop links to such posts in our [PMSE Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management), so you should drop in occasionally to see if there's anything new there.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question fits better on PM.SE as compared to Workplace.SE because it is about roles in a software project management methodology. This will be a good addition to the content of PM.SE. We have had a somewhat related question earlier [Is the Product Owner the boss of a Scrum Team?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/is-the-product-owner-the-boss-of-a-scrum-team).

Answer (score 3):

I also agree this question fits better here, and it's also supported by the comments on the question. Workplace.SE audience isn't used to the Scrum terms / methodology as PM.SE audience, so this question might get more answers / thoughts when shared with a community with more background on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The community should be able to contribute to answering it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been migrated to our site at the request of the original poster.